# Need help verifying identity using logical connectives

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently going through Velleman's How To Prove It in order to prepare for proofs in university. I came across the following question and am having quite a bit of trouble with it.

Verify that the following is true:

$(A\Delta B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \Delta (B\cap C)$

It's clear through the distributive property that they are equivalent. However, whenever I try verifying the identity through logical connectives, I run into some problems. For example, when I expand the left-hand side expression, I get this:

$(A\lor B) \land \lnot (A \land B) \land C$

But when I do the second one, I get:

$((A \land C) \lor (B \land C)) \land \lnot (A \land C \land B \land C)$

$= C \land (A \lor B) \land \lnot (A \land B \land C)$

The two are not equivalent, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Isn't the statement you're trying to prove to do with sets rather than logic?

Comment: I thought it will have to do with logic as well due to the connectives, but it is a question more about sets I guess. I'll change the tag, thanks.

Comment: I'm confused - which connectives? As far as I can see, you're proving that intersection is distributive over set difference here.

Comment: To be forward with you, I don't know what I'm doing. I just wanted to verify the identity and was using logical connectives such as and, or, and not to do so.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference. This isn't to do with logic